# IP conflict: AP has same IP as another network intereface

Tags: networking

I'm designing a Linux based product that will have two wireless network interfaces (wlan0 and wlan1). The product is configured for wlan0 to be STA and wlan1 to be AP. The AP on each product has a static IP of 192.168.4.1 and a DHCP server configured to respond to IP requests on wlan1 only. The plan is for the customer to buy multiple devices and connect to the (master) first device's AP. The master will then query for the other device APs (the slaves), connect and configure their STAs to connect to it's (the master) AP.  The problem is when the master's STA connects to a slave's AP (or vise versa) it tends to send packets for IP 192.168.4.1 to it's own AP instead of the one the STA is connected to.

How do I solve this problem? I apologize for lack of political correctness.

Comment: It would help if you explained which design you have chosen for the IPv6 configuration of these devices.

Comment: I don't see any part of the question which would be related to IPv6. This question seems to me as "just" IPv4 related.

Comment: @KamilJ To achieve a good design in a new networking product the approach which is most likely to succeed is to first design the IPv6 side of it. Once that's done you use that to guide your IPv4 design which may of course need to differ in some areas due to shortcomings of IPv4. It's quite possible that parts of your design won't even need to be included in the IPv4 scenario since you can rely on the IPv6 solution. In particular the configuration step mentioned in this question could be one which is done once over IPv6 but configures both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: @kasperd: In general you are right but unfortunately IPv6 is not as live in production (especially in case) of small projects as it would be... :-( This not seems to me like a design from scratch but as design like "we have something a we need something new cooperating with what we have"... In case I am right the IPv6 is not a case. IPv6 is working and great but not just a solution for everything. I have personally also face the similar case (how to route several overlapping IP ranges to be able to have several instances out of the box of the environment with predefined IP ranges).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87135/discussion-between-kasperd-and-kamil-j).

Answer (score 0):

In general this is not the good approach as once the IP is local on the sytem, the routing is just going to it. In case there is other option how to do it, use that other  option to have it clean and clear ;-).

Anyway, let's assume that 192.168.4.1 is just default GW and you want to have other traffic going through this network via the "main" connection...

---

#### NAT is ok (one way connection from "last" client to "main" AP)

In theory you can split the system to network stack and use interconnecting IP and NAT to realize this requirements. With this approach you can even chain the "sub boxes". Only limitation is that all clients behind "sub box" will share the IP of "sub box" from point of view of "upper" AP.

```
AP                                 "sub box"                          client
|                              _________________                             |
|              192.168.4.x(M) /                 \                            |
| --------------------------- |   "default NS"  |                            |
| 192.168.4.1                 |    10.10.0.1    |                            |
|                             | ====== | ====== |                            |
|                             |   10.10.0.2 (M) | 192.168.4.1                |
|                             |       NS2       | -------------------------- |
|                             \_________________/                192.168.4.x |
                              (M) ... MASQUERADE
```

To add new namespace with name **ns2**

```
ip netns add ns2
```

To create "virtual" interface which will interconnect namespaces

```
ip link add pub-link type veth peer name loc-link
```

.... there will be created two interfaces with names **pub-link** and **loc-link**

To move **loc-link** to namespace **ns2**:

```
ip link set loc-link netns ns2
```

To activate and setup IP on **pub-link**

```
ip link set pub-link up
ip address add 10.10.0.1/24 dev pub-link
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

To activate (all necessary stuff) on **loc-link**

```
ip netns exec ns2 ip link set loc-link up
ip netns exec ns2 ip address add 10.10.0.2/24 dev loc-link
ip netns exec ns2 ip route add default via 10.10.0.1
ip netns exec ns2 iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o loc-link -j MASQUERADE
ip netns exec ns2 sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

To move *WLAN1* to namespace **ns2** and "activate it"

```
ip link set wlan1 netns n2
ip netns exec ns2 ip link set wlan1 up 
ip netns exec ns2 ip address add 192.168.4.1/24 dev wlan1
```

All the stuff related to *wlan1* **has to** be run in the same namespace where the interface is located (so in our case **ns2**) - e.g. dhcp server for *wlan1*

```
ip netns exec ns2 <commnad>
```

And the last but not the least we have to set up masquerade on *wlan0*

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**Unfortunately this cannot be realized by system config files so it is not persistent over system reboot. You have to place it to the script and apply it with the reboot / network restart.**

---

#### bi-directional communication ( for "NEW" connection)

In this case you need to remap it and you just cannot use 192.168.4.0/24 as addresses in general to connect to. In case it can be reachable using other network range (once it still use in configuration of each single node the 192.168.4.0/24 network) I would think for example utilizing **NETMAP** target on table **nat** of **iptables** instead of **MASQUERADE** in **ns2** (namespaces will be needed anyway to separate it)... But it is getting far from original request so I would keep it just as a hint ;)...